# How to enter photo mode?

Tags: driveclub

So I'm seeing lots of very nice shared images of Driveclub on social media and I have no idea how people are taking them, short of the 'Share' button.

How can I get into photo mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that you need to click the **right hand side** of the touch pad at any time to enter photo mode, where you can then take your shot.